# Why does the print() function crash my GUI macOS app when it's running as root?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, crash, root

I'm using the `print()` function to print debugging output into the console while debugging my macOS GUI app with Xcode:

```
#if DEBUG
print("\(Date()): something happened")
#endif
```

This works, but when I run my GUI app as `root` (or with administrative privileges) the `print` function crashes the process.

Why? And what shall I use instead?

---

PS. I'm not sure if it's related, I'm also crashing the XCode. Steps to repro: If I have my app running as root, then in XCode, with my app project selected, if I go to the Debug menu (thinking to attach to my process.) Instead the XCode crashes:

[image]

Comment: Use Logger? It's way better in any case. Though I don't know if it will solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have a crashlog?

Comment: Can you please post the traceback, [fully symbolicated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report)? Also, does the Xcode debugger show any errors otherwise?

Comment: @MrDeveloper it should be as an `.ips` file, right? But where is it saved if the process is running as root?

Comment: @koen where do I look for it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=nra79npr

Comment: I believe `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` and it might have a `.crash` extension - a `.ips` file is the app package. For example: `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/[YourAppName]_2023-04-03-XXXXXX.crash`, where the `XXXXXX` is the timestamp.

Comment: This may be a privilege protection between riot user and the user you use to start the app from xCode : the console belongs to user and root may have no write to print in it.

Comment: @koen my app is not in the app store. So I can't use it.

Comment: @MrDeveloper the `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` directory has a few `.diag` files only. None for my app though. Any more ideas where I can find a crash dump for it?

Comment: If you open Console, you should see all crash reports under the Crash Reports option in the sidebar. I am able to find crash reports for all apps there, and I can open them in Finder. Looking at those, I think you are right about the `.ips` file extension. If you cannot find the reports in Console, I would also check your app's container folder as it might end up storing the reports there.

Comment: @MrDeveloper I couldn't find it in either of those locations. But now though, I managed to crash XCode when I attempted to attach to my root process (see my OP for details). And I found an `.ips` file for the xcode crash. Do you need it?

Comment: No thank you, I am working on a solution now. Also, how are you running your app as root? With `sudo`, or something else?

Comment: @MrDeveloper using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges`